# Unable to resolve "mobx-react/native" from "node_modules/react-native-router-flux/dist/Router.js"

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-router-flux

Im using expo.

here's my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "emmunize",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "jest-expo": "27.0.0",
        "react-native-scripts": "^1.14.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
    },
    "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native-scripts start",
        "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
        "android": "react-native-scripts android",
        "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
        "expo": "^27.0.0",
        "firebase": "^5.0.2",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "native-base": "^2.5.2",
        "react": "16.3.1",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz",
        "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
        "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.32",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "redux": "^4.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
    }
}
```

I dont know what happened, when I try to exp start and exp android this error appeaars. I've followed the latest exp version 27 https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v27-0-0-is-now-available-898bf1e5b0e4 but I think react-native-router-flux has an issue with the latest expo version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was create a new project. As this is the new beta we should wait to the group can solve the bug.

**Provisional Solution**

- Open terminal
- Go to project path... Example: user/Documents/ReactNative/(name your project)/
- run the command: npm remove react-native-router-flux
- run the command: npm install react-native-router-flux@4.0.0-beta.28
- run project again to try

react-native-router-flux@4.0.0-beta.28 is a version that i used in the last project and work fine.